# toggling active class on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I have a button group i am toggeling active class on. Only one button can have class actibve

```
toggleActive: function(e) {

            var format;

            e.preventDefault();

            $(e.currentTarget).parent().siblings().children().removeClass("active");  

            $(e.currentTarget).addClass("active");
```

it works fine on desktop, but i doesn't on mobile when user can use two fingers and tap two buttons at the same time and both of them are getting class active at the same time.
How can i sole this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using an if statement with jQuery's hasClass function? http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('.buttonGroup').hasClass("active") ) {
     $('.buttonGroup').removeClass("active"); 
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```